# Subroutines in Verilog (used by ModelSim)

Tags: verilog, verification

I am having a problem getting subroutines working in Verilog. I am following several tutorials and I cannot get my verilog files to compile. Here is a shortened version of my code.

```
module name(/*stuff*/)
inputs /*stuff*/
outputs /*stuff*/

initial begin
/*stuff*/
end

   //Simple reset task
    task reset_module ();
        reset[1] = 1;
        #(`CLOCK_CYCLE*4) 
        reset[1] = 0;
        #(`CLOCK_CYCLE*4)
    endtask

endmodule
```

The compiler complains about the endtask keyword being unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add semicolons to the end of the delay lines:

```
task reset_module();
  reset[1] = 1;
  #(`CLOCK_CYCLE*4); 
  reset[1] = 0;
  #(`CLOCK_CYCLE*4);
endtask
```

Comment: Thank you. The delay statements worked without semicolons within the module. So this was very frustrating.

Comment: dave_59 explains it pretty well; but essentially delay constructs are modifiers to statements, not statements on their own unless you add a semicolon (still a modifier, just on an empty statement).

Comment: One input from my side. Verilog must have `begin..end` in a function/task call. Multiple statement functions and tasks without a begin/end are only supported in SystemVerilog.

Answer (score 1):

A semi-colon is needed after the last delay construct. That's because the `#(expression)` construct is not really a complete statement, it's a statement modifier. Each statement can can have any number of delay constructs (like `#(expr) @(expr)` )  in front of it. If you need a delay construct at the end of a procedural block of statement, you need a null statement, which is just a semi-colon.